# SPD Workflow skip a step

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm trying to create a workflow that's seems like it should be simple, but I can't seem to tick all my boxes. Essentially it's because a step can be skipped sometimes.

Item is entered - workflow starts

Step 1: Status changes to "choice A" Workflow sends an email to "person A"

Step 2: Status Change to "choice B" Workflow sends an email to "person A" (this step can be skipped as sometimes "choice B" doesn't occur on certain items. these items are identified by another choice column and i can't use content type for these items either)

Step 3: Status changes to "Choice C" Workflow pauses (usually the change to "Choice C" to "Date A" is 6 months-year) until "date A" workflow sends different email based on "Type" to "person B". Date A is also not determined until "Choice C" is reached.

end

I've played around with a few methods but my biggest problem is that sometimes step 2 gets skipped, also there are days if not weeks between each step. The list will be about 2-3000 items, so I'm hesitant to use two workflows on each item. any ideas out there? I feel like this should be simple and I'm missing something.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the second step in a condition and check if the value of your choice column is set or match it against a certain string or something.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? i've added an image of what I currently have, can you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

got it, i used if else. so it goes if step two, step three. else step three. step three is written twice, once inside step two and as the else.

Answer (score 0):

If else condition will be the best choice in designer workflow while nested if condition may be complicated if you have more conditions. If you have access to Flow, there are much easier way to do it with a switch condition to handle occasions like this.